# Cross-compiling Slackware: is the build order listed anywhere?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, source, packaging, slackware

I'm building a Slackware system from source and hitting a dependency wall here. (Before you ask: no, I'm not trying to "make it faster"; I'm building against a different C library.) Getting a toolchain and the very basics (coreutils, archivers, shell, perl, kernel, etc.) was simple enough, but when I look at the remaining several hundred packages I don't know what order they need to be built in to meet their dependencies.

Looking through the various docs I don't see any build order listed, and there's no master build script either, just the individual packages' SlackBuilds. And .tgz's don't list dependencies like deb's or RPM's do. Is this just something Patrick keeps in his head that the rest of us mortals will have to figure out manually, or am I missing a doc somewhere?

I tried using BLFS but Slackware seems to build X much earlier in the process than BLFS does. I suppose I can simply try to build everything, note when dependencies fail, and manually make a dependency tree, but I'm hoping there's just a build list somewhere I'm missing...

Comment: If and when you finish this, please edit your question to let everyone know where your documentation and project ended up.  It sounds very interesting.

Comment: You ought to try asking this question over at the Slackware forums: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ Patrick might answer your question himself.

Comment: WhiteHotLoveTiger: Thanks, I forgot I had an account there. I'll see if Patrick or somebody else can help me.

Bruce Ediger: you can follow my kvetchings about this (musl is incredibly anal about namespaces, it turns out) at http://muslack.org I'll post whatever tree I end up building or finding.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone looking, the good folks at linuxquestions.org and the slackware IRC channel pointed me in the right direction.

1. Slackware is not generally built from scratch; the releases are more like freezes of a constantly-moving build system. That said,
2. The [ARM port scripts](http://taper.alienbase.nl/mirrors/alienarm/bootstrap/) have the order that is what someone porting to a new architecture or toolchain will need.